# How do I get current icon theme name in linux?

Tags: icons, themes, xdg

Im writing small TODO applet for conky in lua. Id like to display small icon next to task, which matches current icon theme.

I have already read which icon to look for on [freedesktop.rg](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#names).

How to get name of current theme, so i can find appropriate icon?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome uses dconf at path `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/icon-theme`

Just do `dconf watch /` and change the icon theme, it will show what dconf prop is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

I found the answer in [this AskUbuntu.com tread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765569/how-to-determine-which-theme-is-currently-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora, check:

- Global configuration: `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`
- User configuration: Create or edit `~/.icons/default/index.theme`

Find:

```
[Icon Theme]
Inherits=Adwaita
```

There is the default icon theme!